# Confused about textbooks reasoning for cauchy estimate

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

Suppose we have that $$f(z)=(z^3+1)e^{z^2}$$ on the unit disk.

My textbook says,

"obviously"

$$|f(z)| \le 2 |e^{z^2}|=e^{x^2-y^2} \le e$$ for all $z \in D(0,1)$

So I fully understand where the 2 comes from but I am not so sure about the $|e^{z^2}|$

$$e^{z^2}=e^{x^2-y^2+2xyi}=e^{x^2-y^2}e^{2xyi}$$

So my thoughts are maybe that the norm of $e^{2xyi}=1$ because it can be written using euler formula and then it will follow from Pythagoras.

But if that is the case, where does the 2 go in the first estimate?

So in the comments I explain why I am still confused on what is correct and not

Comment: You forgot a modulus, $\lvert e^{2xyi}\rvert = 1$. That the $2$ disappears is a mistake. Since $f(1) = 2e$, we see that the bound $2e$ is sharp.

Comment: I should clarify, the book is the part that has the 2 gone, (Krantz complex variables, pg 95)

Comment: Book authors make mistakes too.

Comment: but they still come to the same conclusion for f'(1/2) as they have it is less then or equal to e/(1/2)=2e

Comment: So is that just because they happen to evaluate at (1/2)? because doing it my way, we would get it less then or equal to 2e/(1/2)=e instead of 2e?

Comment: So im still confused now about which one is correct?